# 403: Forbidden, Actions on Google push notifications from another project

Tags: permissions, actions-on-google, google-cloud-iam

I am registering userUpdateIds returned from update_permission in a Firestore database. I now want to send a notification to all users in this database from within another (my main) project. Calling the send API with the credentials from the (main) project gives me a 403: forbidden error even though the (main) project is configured as 'owner' of the project that registered the users.

Is there a way to send notifications from another project than the one that registered them? Or do I need to pass a service account key to the main project so I can authenticate myself as the registering project?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be passing push notifications around. Is there a way to proxy the call from your primary project to a Cloud Function on your other project?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes, there is. Perhaps that's indeed a better way, thank you. I wasn't sure whether I was just doing something wrong or if it was not possible to send push notifications from another project on purpose.

Comment: It may be feasible, though I couldn't say exactly where the issue is happening.